# How to break down and print two list of lists together in Python?

Tags: python, list, printing, tuples

Here are two lists:

```
a_value = [[0.234, 0.88,0.98],[0.923,0.777,0.87],[0.77,0.98,0.89]]
b_value = [[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)],[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)],[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)]]
```

I need to join the two lists such that I have output that prints as:

```
Set1
b_value (1,1) = a_value 0.234
b_value (1,2) = a_value 0.88
b_value (1,3) = a_value 0.98
Set2
b_value (1,1) = a_value 0.923
b_value (1,2) = a_value 0.777
b_value (1,3) = a_value 0.87
Set 3
b_value (1,1) = a_value 0.77
b_value (1,2) = a_value 0.98
b_value (1,3) = a_value 0.89
```

The code that I have attempted looks like:

```
print("\n".join([('b_value{} a_value={}'.format(i,j)) for i,j in zip(b_value,a_value)]))
```

Output:

```
b_value[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)] a_value=[0.234, 0.88, 0.98]
b_value[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)] a_value=[0.923, 0.777, 0.87]
b_value[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)] a_value=[0.77, 0.98, 0.89]
```

I am not sure how to modify the code such that it breaks down the list of lists and also separates them into "Sets".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you only need to *print* the values and not build a list, you should use `for` loops instead of the *list comprehension*. And then you  also need to `zip` the *sublists* in a nested loop to place their items side-by-side:

```
for idx, (i ,j) in enumerate(zip(b_value,a_value), 1):
    print("Set{}".format(idx))
    for a,b in zip(i,j):
        print('b_value {} = a_value {}'.format(a,b))
```

---

```
Set1
b_value (1, 1) = a_value 0.234
b_value (1, 2) = a_value 0.88
b_value (1, 3) = a_value 0.98
Set2
b_value (1, 1) = a_value 0.923
b_value (1, 2) = a_value 0.777
b_value (1, 3) = a_value 0.87
Set3
b_value (1, 1) = a_value 0.77
b_value (1, 2) = a_value 0.98
b_value (1, 3) = a_value 0.89
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to flatten the two lists, if you want to do this in a single line I'd use `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain

a_value = [[0.234, 0.88,0.98],[0.923,0.777,0.87],[0.77,0.98,0.89]]
b_value = [[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)],[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)],[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)]]

print("\n".join([('b_value{} a_value={}'.format(i,j)) for i,j in zip(chain.from_iterable(b_value),chain.from_iterable(a_value))]))
```

However, if you need a faster method of flattening, use a few extra lines:

```
a_value = [[0.234, 0.88,0.98],[0.923,0.777,0.87],[0.77,0.98,0.89]]
b_value = [[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)],[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)],[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)]]

flat_a = [item for sublist in a_value for item in sublist]
flat_b = [item for sublist in b_value for item in sublist]

print("\n".join([('b_value{} a_value={}'.format(i,j)) for i,j in zip(flat_b,flat_a)]))
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have the formatting part ok, but having trouble combining the lists correctly. Why not flatten them first?

```
a = [[0.234, 0.88,0.98],[0.923,0.777,0.87],[0.77,0.98,0.89]]
b = [[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)],[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)],[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)]]

flat_a = [item for sublist in a for item in sublist]
flat_b = [item for sublist in b for item in sublist]
zip(flat_a, flat_b)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how general you want this code, but this prints out want you want I think:

```
for myset in zip(a_value,b_value):
    for i in range(len(myset) + 1):
        print("b_value " + str(myset[1][i]) + " = a_value " + str(myset[0][i]))
```